# integer64 not assigned NA values during data.table::dcast(), but defaults to 9218868437227407266

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table named test where the 'freq' column is of class integer64, as follows

```
>test
    event_type eventdt_qtr  freq
 1:         IF      200601    23
 2:       BDSF      200601    47
 3:       EDPM      200601   258
 4:       CPBP      200601    17
 5:         EF      200601  5132
 6:       EPWS      200601    96
 7:         EF      200602 15929
 8:         IF      200602    24
 9:       BDSF      200602    41
10:       CPBP      200602    16
11:       EDPM      200602   231
12:       EPWS      200602   109
13:       CPBP      200603    15
14:         IF      200603    42
15:       EDPM      200603   358
16:       BDSF      200603    72
17:       EPWS      200603    93
18:        DPA      200603     2
19:         EF      200603 48185
20:       BDSF      200604    47

>str(chk_1_1_means)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  297 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ event_type : chr  "IF" "BDSF" "EDPM" "CPBP" ...
 $ eventdt_qtr: num  200601 200601 200601 200601 200601 ...
 $ freq       :integer64 23 47 258 17 5132 96 15929 24 ...
```

When I do data.table::dcast() operation on test, instead of getting NA or 0 for non existing event_type and eventdt_qtr combinations, I get the value 9218868437227407266. I believe this issue might be related to [Merge (outer join) fails to set NAs for integer64](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1385), but I dont know how to fix it.

```
> test_tx <- data.table::dcast(test,eventdt_qtr ~ event_type,value.var = "freq")
> test_tx
   eventdt_qtr BDSF                CPBP                 DPA                EDPM                  EF
1:      200601   47                  17 9218868437227407266                 258                5132
2:      200602   41                  16 9218868437227407266                 231               15929
3:      200603   72                  15                   2                 358               48185
4:      200604   47 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266
                  EPWS                  IF
1:                  96                  23
2:                 109                  24
3:                  93                  42
4: 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266
```

Note: I know there is a fix (see solution below) if I do explicit conversion of column 'freq' to integer instead of integer64, but I don't want to do any type conversions as I am reading the data from Redshift and have to preserve the structure of the data.table 'test' downstream in the code.

```
> test$freq <- as.integer(test$freq)
> test_tx <- data.table::dcast(test,eventdt_qtr ~ event_type,value.var = "freq")
> test_tx
   eventdt_qtr BDSF CPBP DPA EDPM    EF EPWS IF
1:      200601   47   17  NA  258  5132   96 23
2:      200602   41   16  NA  231 15929  109 24
3:      200603   72   15   2  358 48185   93 42
4:      200604   47   NA  NA   NA    NA   NA NA
```

Comment: on my end I am unable to reproduce your problem

Comment: Let me try to give a reproducible example for the test data.table. Thanks @Onyambu